# Linear dependence of rational numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that two arbitrary rational numbers 
\begin{equation}
x=\frac{a}{b} \ \ \text{and} \ \ y=\frac{c}{d}
\end{equation}
are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 7):

With $\alpha=bc$ and $\beta=-ad$ we have
$$\alpha x+\beta y=0$$